# How to solve for $y$ here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I’ve been working on an initial value problem that I want to solve for $y$ in. I’ve reached:
$$\frac{y-4}{y+1}=(e^{-t}+C)^5$$
But I’m not sure where to go from here. How can I solve for $y$? Thanks.

Note: if you all need the steps I took to get to this point, I can provide that, but either way I don’t know how to solve for $y$ from here.

Comment: "algebra-precalculus" and "ordinary differential equations" are contradictory tags.

Comment: @fleablood: ...and yet the OP claims to have correctly solved an ODE, but is struggling with the precalculus algebra necessary to conclude.  Sometimes, reality is stranger than fiction.

Comment: @Jacob is your comment supposed to be offensive? What’s the objective of it?

Comment: @Jacob I was drawing a blank on this one. And I happened to have integrated incorrectly in the first place. I was able to fix it after a few minutes though

Comment: @Jacob keep in mind, I wasn’t practicing too much math over this past summer and just returned to school, so it’d be appreciated if you could keep your snarky comments to yourself, thanks

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins: No, I'm not trying to be offensive at all!  My point is that you put the correct tags on here, even though we wouldn't expect them to show up together.

Comment: (Sorry if that wasn't clear.)

Comment: @Jacob oh ok. I read it differently, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{y-4}{y+1}=(e^{-t}+C)^5$$
Multiply with $y+1$:
$$y-4=(y+1)(e^{-t}+C)^5\\
y-4=y(e^{-t}+C)^5+(e^{-t}+C)^5\\
y-y(e^{-t}+C)^5=(e^{-t}+C)^5+4\\
y=\frac{(e^{-t}+C)^5+4}{1-(e^{-t}+C)^5}$$

Comment: I will never know how people do this so fast. Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. You’ve got the checkmark as long as I remember to grant it

Comment: Just practice. At some point some of the patterns to solve problems become automatic.

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins:  one thing is to recognize that the right side is just some stuff.  You can call it $x$ if you want because you won't be taking it apart.  Then you just clear the fraction and solve a linear equation.

Comment: @RossMillikan that’d help. It wasn’t very obvious to me what I should do for some reason.

Comment: @Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins. It's just simple high school algebra.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{y-4}{y+1}=(e^{-t}+C)^5$$
$$\frac{y+1-5}{y+1}=(e^{-t}+C)^5$$
$$1-\frac{5}{y+1}=(e^{-t}+C)^5$$
$$\frac{5}{y+1}=1-(e^ {-t}+C)^5$$
$$\frac{y+1}5=\dfrac 1{1-(e^{-t}+C)^5}$$
$${y+1}=\dfrac 5{1-(e^{-t}+C)^5}$$
$$\implies y(t)=\dfrac 5{1-(e^{-t}+C)^5}-1$$